# Libraries and API to be used for developing a React Native Video Chat App?

Tags: react-native, video, chat

Can anyone recommend me libraries and APIs I can use to develop a video chat app using React Native? I would appreciate it if your suggestions doesn't require you to pay in order to fully utilize the library/api.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've used this [jitsi-meet](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-jitsi-meet) library. It's pretty easy to use it ,and also it integrates all the webrtc module by itself and also it gives a ready made UI.For you to start instantly you can use this library, even ive launched an app both on playstore and appstore for video calling.

And if you wnat the full custom way, you can use [rn-webrtc](https://github.com/react-native-webrtc/react-native-webrtc) , here you have to make your own UI and manage everything.

Hope it helps. feel free for doubts

Comment: Thanks for your recommendation! I'll go ahead and check it

Comment: @Seaghan great, do check it, and also if you think answer is correct , you can mark it as accepted , would help :)

Comment: @Seaghan https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.mysabha.app&hl=en this is the app, you can check it, ive created using jitsi